# Sum all odd indexes in an array

Tags: java, arrays

I have to complete a program according to these instructions:

```
public class SumOddIndex {
    public static void main(String[] args){
       int[] array = {1,1,8,4,2,6};
       // Call the method sum, receive an integer value, and print the value on output. 
       // A call passing the example array should result in a value of 11. 
       // Use a while loop.
   }
```

Here code a method called sum. The method sum should take an int - array as argument and return the sum of all values in all array cells that have an odd index number.
USE A WHILE- LOOP!
    }

This is what I have tried so far, but it is not working.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = {1, 1, 8, 4, 2, 6};
        sum(array);
}

public static int sum(int[] y){
   int sum = 0;
   int i = 0;
   while(y.len

   public static int sum(int[] y) {
      int sum = 0;
      int i = 0;
      while (y.length%2 == 1) {
         //y.length%2 == 1;
         sum += y[i];
         i++;
      }
      System.out.println(y[i]);
      return i;
   }
}
```

Comment: `y.length%2` - tell me what this is.

Comment: i think i can calculate so all odd elements of my array but i think i am wrong :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are using java, try something like this:

```
int i = 0;
int sum = 0;
while(i < myArray.length){
   sum += myArray[i];
   i++;
}
```

This is a while loop that will execute only as long as your counter variable is less than the size of the array (that way you will never have an index out of bounds). Inside the loop, it will add to the sum the value at the index of the counter.

Don't forget to increment your counter inside the while loop, or you will be stuck inside an infinite loop.

**EDIT**

I misread your question, but if you only want to sum odd values, try this:

```
while(i < myArray.length){
   if(myArray[i] % 2 == 1){ // If value is odd
      sum += myArray[i];
   }
   i++;
}
```

**EDIT 2**

To only sum odd indexes, change the above code to check if your counter is odd instead of the value at that index, like this:

```
while(i < myArray.length){
   if(i % 2 == 1){ // If index is odd
      sum += myArray[i];
   }
   i++;
}
```

Or, you could start you indexing at 1 and increase by 2 each time. I will only give psuedocode for this one:

```
// Start counter at 1
// While counter is less than array length
// Add element's value to the sum
// Increment counter by 2
```

Comment: hmm no it doesn't work so i need a while loop, witch sums the element of 1 3 and 5. so that the result is 11

Comment: this is definitely not the optimal solution...instead starting i at 1 and incrementing by 2 would be ideal

Comment: @Saboteur Are you sure you're adding to the sum and not just setting sum equal to the value?

Comment: no i am not sure :/ i am trying to solve this one now for 2 hours :/ the public static int sum was created by me. i don't knwow if its correct or not...this is because i am here ;)

Comment: Do you have `sum = myArray[i]` or `sum += myArray[i]` in your code?

Comment: //Here code a method called sum. The method sum should take an
//int
-
array as argument and return the sum of all values
//in all array cells that have an odd index number.
USE A WHILE
-
LOOP!

Comment: @Saboteur isn't that what we're doing? The code above works for me.

Comment: @saboteur It shouldn't. Are you sure you have `sum += myArray[i]`? If you have `sum = myArray[i]` without the `+` sign, it won't work right.

Comment: Glad we worked it out. Feel free to accept the answer if it works for you.

Answer (score 2):

Using Streams in Java 8 you can use `IntStream` and `filter` and `reduce` down to a total sum:

```
int[] array = {1,1,8,4,2,6};
int sum = IntStream.range(0, array.length).filter(i -> i % 2 == 1).map(i -> array[i]).sum();
```

Comment: This is old but incorrect, the .filter just adds the indexes up, not the values.

Comment: @awm thanks for pointing that out, I believe the update should contain a valid solution.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question has been answered already, but I thought it would still help out.

```
int i = 1;
int sum = 0;

while(i < myArray.length)
{            
    sum += myArray[i];  
    i += 2;
}

return sum;
```

I added @Logan Murphy's suggestion for optimization.

Comment: This works, but if you're starting at 1 and incrementing by 2 each time, why check if it's odd? Unless something goes terribly wrong, `i` will always be odd now.

Comment: Woops, I forgot to take that out.

Answer (score 0):

Use stream's filter and reduce operation.

int[] array = {1,1,8,4,2,6};
int sum = array.stream().filter(s -> s % 2 != 0).reduce(0, Integer::sum);

Answer (score 0):

A bit optimized approach can be to calculate and store the length of the array in a variable once, instead of calculating it in each iteration.

```
public int oddIndSum(int [] myArray){
    int i = 1;
    int sum = 0;
    int length = myArray.length;
    while(i < length){
        if(i % 2 == 1){ // If index is odd then add
        sum += myArray[i];
        }
        i++;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: HI @MohammadWael - why not add your contribution to the original accepted answer from Nov 2014?  Perhaps consider using `final int length`?